# problemas de conecxion con el jdbc

Tags: java, mysql

se contava con un proyecto de mysql 5.7 se realizo la actualizacion a 8.1 pero al momento de realizar la actualizacion , ya no funciono el jdbc realize actualizacion y sigue marcando el mismo el mismo error que es este [![
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Tf4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Tf4.png)

Comment: tu servidor es mysql server 5.7 o la versión 8.1, workbench es solo una interfaz gráfica para conectarte al servidor y desde ahi hacer tareas

Comment: por otro lado mysql 8 supone una actuialización al protocolo de cifrado de contraseñas, entonces el driver que usabas para conectarte con la versión 5.7 ya no te servir+a; necesitas la nueva versión de ese driver